# Get Search keyword in URL

Tags: php

```
<form action="">
    <input placeholder="SEARCH" name="search_input" type="text"/>
    <input type="submit" name="search_submit"/>
</form>
```

If people search by "Keyword Item" I want URL will be http://mydomain.com/search?keywords=Keyword%20Item

How can I do it? I know needs configure in form action, get etc.

Thanks in advance.

## Update

When I am trying with this code

```
<form action="http://search.golfoutletsusa.com/search?" method="get">
    <input placeholder="SEARCH" name="Keywords" type="text"/>
    <input type="submit" name="search_submit"/>
</form>
```

The URL is: http://search.golfoutletsusa.com/search?Keywords=85&search_submit=Submit+Query

I just want "&search_submit=Submit+Query" will be removed from URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:1**

You can add the following code at the top of your search.php (or, whatever the processor file):

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["search_submit"]))
    {
        $keywords = $_GET["Keywords"];
        header("Location: search.php?Keywords=$keywords");
    }
?>
```

**OR**

**Solution:2**

You can omit the name of submit button if it is not really necessary to give it a name. So instead of

```
<input type="submit" name="search_submit"/>
```

just use

```
<input type="submit" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php echo $_GET["keywords"]; ?>
```

You will need to change the name of the text field from search_input to keywords though.

You should also consider using an `id` attribute along with the `name`. And as the other answer says, form `action` and `method` should be set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Set `action` of the form to `search.php` and `method` to `get`.

Then change the `name` of your `input` element to `keywords`.

But still the url won't be - `http://mydomain.com/search?keywords=Keyword%20Item`

It will be - `http://mydomain.com/search.php?keywords=Keyword%20Item`

Answer (score 1):

Simply put everything in the form properties, only you have to select a file which will receive all this, /search will not suffice:

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="keywords" placeholder="SEARCH" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

EDIT: In the search.php file you would get the variable contents with the get global variable like this:

```
$search_query = $_GET['keywords'];
```

After that you simply write the rest of the code to do the search... Note that this would lead to an URL like http://www.example.com/search.php?keywords=query

Comment: then what need I do in search.php?